# create .net web service proxy classes without a WSDL

Tags: .net, web-services

I have a question about manually creating a .Net webservice proxy class. The WSDL is unavailable, and it is a Websphere server. I was able to create a class that inherits from System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol and send the request however I’m having one difficulty.  The  element has to have an attribute called “targetID” and I don’t know how to get this added.  Currently I have a class called CQuery that has two strings (firstname and lastname) so that as it is sent it serializes it out to:

```
.<query>
 ..<firstname></firstname>
 ..<lastname>LastName</lastname>
 .</query>
```

But it is suppose to look like: (and actually ‘millennium_8dea22d9e8b25d0f’ should be a variable as it could change)

```
.<query targetID='millennium_8dea22d9e8b25d0f'>
..<firstname></firstname>
..<lastname>LastName</lastname>
.</query>
```

Any ideas on how to get it to serialize this way, or any direction I should go?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a targetID property to your class, and mark it with the `[XmlAttribute]` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Create a Web service yourself. Create a proxy. Then take cues from the generated proxy code.